# Does "EasyMock.expectLastCall();" do anything without a further call to resulting IExpectationSetters?

Tags: void, easymock

Consider this code snippet:-

```
Whatever mock = EasyMock.createMock( Whatever.class );
mock.doSomething();
EasyMock.expectLastCall();   // <- Does this do anything?
EasyMock.replay( whatever );
```

Does `expectLastCall()` here actually do anything?  Adding or removing this line from my test appears to make no difference.

Obviously it is useful if you add `.andThrow` or `.atLeastOnce()`, etc. to the call.  That is not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you only usually use `expectLastCall()` when you need the result to specify behaviour. That's its purpose.

Of course, it does no *harm* to call it if you find it makes your test more readable. For example, I might do that for consistency - if I've *had* to call it twice in order to specify more behaviour, I might include it a third time even if I didn't need to. I'd probably add the default behaviour explicitly though, just for additional consistency.